# Gradle Plugin defaultDependencies jar programmatically

Tags: android, maven, gradle, groovy

```
protected static String projectCompile = "com.example.project:0.0.1"
projectConfig.defaultDependencies { 
   DependencySet dependencies ->
        dependencies.add(project.dependencies.create(projectCompile))
}
```

This gets the dependency from the Maven repository.

I want to dependency on the local repository jar.

Who knows how?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot influence where a dependency is got from at dependency declaration time. You just say "I need 'com.example.project:0.0.1', get it for me wherever you find it". In the `repositories` block of the build script you define which repositories are queried for the declared dependencies and in which order. If you want `mavenLocal()` to be looked at first, you have to declare it before `mavenCentral()`. but actually, version `0.0.1` should be identical in both. If version `0.0.1` (opposed to `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`) is different in different repositories, this is very bad and something is likely screwed up. Same versions of a software should always be identical.